What is the URL & port for auto-updating Eaton Intelligent Power Protector UPS software?
Eaton IPP used to support auto-update at http://pqsoftware.eaton.com. This domain is no longer maintained, though the IPP software is still maintained (update released October, 2024). They have not bothered to update the auto-update URL in the config file. The URL is configured in /usr/local/eaton/IntelligentPowerProtector/configs/config.js under cfg.autoUpdate.updateLocation.
Attempts to check for updates result in HTTP 301 (when using port 80) or 503 (when using port 443). Anyone know the current update server URL?
For reference, I'm running IPP version 1.75.183 on Ubuntu Linux. The error from the UI is:
Message: HTTP Error
Details: Update data file could not be read from remote host. Response status: '503'


A downvote without an explanation. How lame.

Eaton has abandoned the internal updates, and now require a manual update process.
